# How do I fill a div with the background-image when it is a container for a smaller div but has no other content?

Tags: css, image, background, hover, size

I'm making some coding, where I'd like to hover over anywhere on an image to access a hover. but I don't want an entire block of coloured semi-transparent padding to cover the picture, only a thin solid-coloured strip.

To make this happen, I created a container for the div and put the smaller, solid-coloured div inside it. However, the background to the container (the image) isn't showing up. I assume this is because the div hasn't got any content other than the smaller div.

How can I fix this?

```
    <center><div style="width: 500px; height: auto; background: #80c4ff; padding: 10px;">
    <div class="dewisidebar">
    <div style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/80x350'); width: 80px; height: 350px;">
    <div class="dewisidecontainer"><div class="dewisidelinks">
    Three<br>Links<br>Here
    </div></div></div></div>

    <div class="dewitracker">
Information here
    </div>
    </div></center>

    <style type="text/CSS">

    .dewisidebar {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #ff80c4;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'times new roman';
    size: 10px;
    color: black;
    }

    .dewisidecontainer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 130px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    }

    .dewisidecontainer:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    }

    .dewisidelinks {
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ff80c4;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 130%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    }

    .dewitracker {
    width: 370px;
    height: 350px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #c4ff80;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'times new roman';
    size: 10px;
    color: black;
    }
    </style>
```

Please help :)

Comment: Could you please reword this, sorry not following what your getting at? Do you just want to be able to have a hover message above the image?

Comment: @DavidGilliam yeah, I basically do, however everything in my coding works the way I want it to at the moment, except the image (the placehold.it/80x350 one) isn't covering the div as a background. background-size doesn't seem to help at all, but if I change the padding of the div to make the picture show, then it will change the position of the "dewisidelinks" div inside the "dewisidecontainer" div?

I hope this makes a little more sense...

Comment: @DavidGilliam In fact, I'm sorry, that was probably just as unclear. It's very early here.  

I guess what I'm asking, written better, is how to make a background image fill a div without any content. Because in this case, the content that is there doesn't seem to affect the background size at all.

Comment: I exaggerated this but something of this sort?? http://jsfiddle.net/davygxyz/s2kyu3gv/

Comment: @DavidGilliam I'm not really sure what I'm looking at on that page... it shows up differently in chrome and IE (I use both regularly)  however, I think I've just discovered why the background-image wasn't appearing in my coding, and it's because something (don't know if it was down to the host or the browser) didn't accept the placeholder as an image because it didn't finish with .jpg/.png etc... I'm sorry for wasting your time >.<  it's always after you post that you figure out the answer. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured out!! You led me to a new site( http://placehold.it ) which I have never heard of. Thank you for that :).Also, IE still needs to catch up a little with certain things.

Comment: No problem, placehold.it is amazingly helpful, when they work! XD This is the first time it hasn't for me though.

With this and ipsum lorem, who needs words or images ever again? XD :P

Answer (score 0):

Took out the extra div you created and added the background to the dewisidebar.
In the CSS I made the background-size 100% 100% meaning that the width and height will be full length of its div.

http://jsfiddle.net/davygxyz/5hxdznz0/

HTML

```
<center><div style="width: 500px; height: auto; background: #80c4ff; padding: 10px;">
    <div class="dewisidebar">
    <div class="dewisidecontainer"><div class="dewisidelinks">
    Three<br>Links<br>Here
</div></div></div>

    <div class="dewitracker">
Information here
    </div>
    </div></center>
```

CSS

```
.dewisidebar {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #ff80c4;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'times new roman';
    size: 10px;
    color: black;

    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/80x350');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    }

    .dewisidecontainer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 130px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    }

    .dewisidecontainer:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    }

    .dewisidelinks {
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ff80c4;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 130%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    }

    .dewitracker {
    width: 370px;
    height: 350px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #c4ff80;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'times new roman';
    size: 10px;
    color: black;
    }
```